# Problem with description of my site and google search

Tags: html, search, google, search-engines

My HTML page :
http://www.faressoft.com

```
<meta name="description" content="فارس سوفت الاسم الرائد في عالم البرمجيات العربية" />
```

When I search for my site name "فارس سوفت" using google, the description contains my description and the error message of my contact form.

why ?

Comment: Should be asked on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your contact form is at the beginning of your page.

Try putting some optimized text before your contact form and you are done.

The "description" meta tag isn't always what google will put in the search result's description.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug with handling flash.  Non-flash would solve your problem.  (Everything there could be done with jQuery easy enough.)

Answer (score 0):

correct your meta tag in html
or other html error check your description
check it is not doubled